# How to have control over this file stream in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node.js-stream

I have a very basic task below, it collects bunch of .md files and pipes them all into a single JSON file with the help of gulp-util's buffer method.

**gulp.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    markdownToJSON = require('gulp-markdown-to-json'),
    marked = require('marked'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('mdtoJSON', () => {
    gulp.src('./test/*.md')
    .pipe(gutil.buffer())
    .pipe(markdownToJSON(marked, 'test/json/itest.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

The issue is that the files are getting processed into the JSON file turn out in an alphabetical order. I've looked into options for gulp.src and gulp-util but I haven't been able to find something that will give me some control over the file order. My ultimate goal is to buffer them according to their creation date.

Is it possible? If so, how and where should I attack this problem?

Comment: I saw this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-viking-posts which looks promising for you.  It handles sort order too, defaults to date descending and does the concat.  Otherwise, you may look into gulp-sort.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/emgeee/gulp-natural-sort which might be your simpler solution.  From https://greenin.space/naturally-sorting-a-filestream-with-gulp/

Comment: thanks for the great suggestions, I ended up solving the issue with underscore.js